# Hot to get the Keyboard Layout language & locale in the format "en_US" in MAC OS X?

Tags: macos, cocoa, keyboard, locale

I'm using Text Input Sources to get the current keyboard layout, which has a name like `com.apple.keylayout.US`.

I want to get the language & locale as `en` and `US` through Cocoa or another system API. I can get the language through `kTISPropertyInputSourceLanguages`.

How could I get the locale?

Comment: The current application locale has nothing to do with the current keyboard layout. What are you trying to do?

Comment: With the deprecated carbon code, it is possible to get the locale and language from the keyboard layout. script  = GetScriptManagerVariable(smKeyScript);
    long layoutId = GetScriptVariable(script, smScriptKeys). I have a function which depends on this format "en-US" and hence need the same return val from the new APIs.

Comment: Do you really need the language and locale associated to the keyboard, or do you just need the language and locale of the current user/application?

Comment: I am using an English locale with a Swedish keyboard. Don't you dare mess with my preferences.

Comment: Could you please expand the question with the code: "using Text Input Sources to get the current keyboard layout, which has a name like com.apple.keylayout.US."

Answer (score 0):

[The Script Manager documentation suggests the replacements for itself, including for the `smScriptKeys` selector.](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Script_Manager/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/c/func/GetScriptVariable)

As for getting the current language or locale, that has nothing to do with the current input source (which may or may not be a keyboard layout) in Mac OS X. This makes sense, as several possible input sources, including several keyboard layouts, are not language- or locale-specific.

Use [CFLocale](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFLocaleRef/) or [NSLocale](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/) to find both the current language(s) and the current locale.